# Hide literal string in .NET

Tags: .net, security, obfuscation, il

If I have a literal string in .NET, as part of a private method, how easy would it be for someone to obtain that string once the project is deployed (assuming no further means of obfuscation)?

I've run across possibilities of viewing hardcoded constants in other languages and am trying to avoid it here.

Reason: for encrypting database connection strings, I want to supply a salt.  The salt must of course be repeatable and reside somewhere within the application, but I know there's many tools available for viewing IL and want to avoid the possibility that a literal string can be read.

I realize that I can use an expression to generate a "one-time random" string that will repeat output, but was particularly curious about private method literal this as I don't have much insight for what's exposed to IL in general.

Comment: You don't have to hide a Salt. But for encrypting connection strings you'll also need a Key. Did you solve that part already?

Comment: Yes, I've got that all squared away, and while I don't really _have_ to hide the salt, I think it'd be better for it to be hidden rather than not. Perhaps I should have stated "as one example" instead of the "reason", because I'm more interested in the general concept of being able to read it rather the connection encryption itself.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a certificate so that during the application runtime, you can read that certificate and use its thumbprint to do the encryption. Installation of the certificate can be done in any of the certificate stores, like the trusted certificate stores.

IMHO, this can be more secure as people do not easily get access to certificate stores in windows servers and your code is free from secrets

Comment: While I like the idea of using a cert thumbprint for encryption, I'm still curious about how readable certain code may be after builds in general (e.g., if I want to toss together a quick utility for internal use, is there an easy way to be reasonably confident that a string couldn't be read from the IL without having to set up certificates or take more complex routes in general?)

Comment: You can take up the obfuscation process which completely protects your library from being disassembled.